# Elementary Direct Product Question

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Here is the problem I'm working on.

Let $G,H$ be groups. Let $\Gamma = \{(g,e_{H}) | \ g \in G\}$ and $\Sigma = \{(e_{G},h) | \ h \in H\}$. Show that for any $x = (g,h) \in G \times H$ we have $x\Gamma x^{-1} = \Gamma$ and $x\Sigma x^{-1} = \Sigma$.

I don't think I even understand what the question is saying: what does it mean to say that $x\Gamma x^{-1}$? Does it mean applying the group operation of $G$ to any elements $x, (g, e_{H}),x^{-1}$ like this: $(g_0,h_0)(g,e_H)(g_0^{-1},h_0^{-1})$ and therefore considering their triple direct-product?

As an example, the question gives the hint that the Chinese remainder theorem shows that $C_n \times C_m$ is isomorphic to $C_{nm}$ if $gcd(n,m) = 1$ but I don't find this particularly informative.

Comment: You have the correct general form for an element of $x\Gamma x^{-1}$, and you need to verify that that general element still lies in $\Gamma$ for the first half of the question set. However, you are using the group operation of $G \times H$, not just of $G$. Also, the product of the three group elements is not a "triple direct product"- the term "direct product" refers to a direct product of several groups (two in the first instance). You are just looking at a product of group elements.

Comment: So is it sufficient to show that $x\Gamma x^{-1} \subseteq \Gamma \Leftrightarrow \Gamma \subseteq x\Gamma x^{-1}$ $-$ and similarly for the case involving $\Sigma$?

Comment: Well, not really: You need to prove that whenever $z \in \Gamma$ and $x \in G \times H$, then $xzx^{-1} \in \Gamma$.